# Updating values of functional data properties doesn't remove old values, only adds new triples

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl, ontology

I have an RDF Ontology with a functional property `hasTrendValue` which relates instances of a class with integer values. I want to change these values programmatically using Jena. I tried the following code:

```java
Property hasTrend = ontModel.getDatatypeProperty(preFix+"hasTrendValue");
Individual regionQualifier = ontModel.getIndividual(activityName); 
ontModel.addLiteral(regionQualifier,hasTrend,34); 

PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ontoPath);
ontModel.write(p,null);
p.close();
```

This code executes correctly but, it does not update the already `hasTrendValue` value in the RDF; instead it adds a new `hasTrendValue` to the RDF ontology even though it declared as a functional property. What is the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDF does not have the concept of "change", only "add" and "remove".  To change a value, you need to remove the old one and add the new one.

Declaring it as a functional property does not change this.  Jena does not check the ontology on every operation.  In fact, a functional property says that the object identifies one thing - it may be written in many ways.  001 and 1 are the same value.  There may be multiple triples, it's not automatically wrong.

Comment: Yap that worked for me, I used statements, created the already existing statement and then removed it from the ontology model and finally save it back.